# Assigning a value to an int variable causing segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a function to read an input from a separate file in C, and arrange this data for further processing. I am, however, running into a segmentation fault when i am trying to assign values to int variables. 
The code looks like this:

```
void read_file1 (char *filename, int *numTrees)
{
  int tempNum;
  char tempStr[1000];
  char line;
  FILE *filer;
  filer = fopen(filename, "r");
  fgets(tempStr, 1000, filer); 
  sscanf(tempStr, "numTrees: %i numLeaves: %i", numTrees, &tempNum);
  /*
     More Code
  */
}

void read_file2 (char  *filename, int *numTrees, int *numLeaves)
{
  char tempStr[1000];
  char line;
  FILE *filer;

  filer = fopen(filename, "r");
  fgets(tempStr, 1000, filer);
  sscanf(tempStr, "numTrees: %i numLeaves: %i", numTrees, numLeaves); //Segmentation fault occurs here
  /*
      More Code
  */
}

int main()
{
  char *filename = "datainput.txt";
  int  *numTrees, *numLeaves;
  read_file2(filename, numTrees, numLeaves);
  return 0;
}
```

The two different read_file functions are meant to arrange the data in different formats. The read_file1 functions works as intended, yet when i try to use a largely identical setup in read_file2,  i get a segmentation fault from the sscanf. The problem seems to lie with the assignment of a value to numTrees, as attempting to assign a value separately also triggers a segmentation fault.
 Which is strange, seeing as the nearly identical read_file1 works fine.

Can anyone tell the issue that is causing the error?

Comment: You have two pointers, `numTrees` and `numLeaves`, but *where do they point?* A pointer must be made to point somewhere valid, otherwise attempting to use it will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Aside: always check that opening a file was successful. In test code you might get away with not checking the return value from `malloc` but that's not so with `fopen`. It is always good to check the return values from `sscanf` and `fgets` too, or your code will crumble at a puff of wind.

Comment: The opening of the file is successfull. As i mentioned, the read_file1, which opens the file in the exact same way, works as intended.

Comment: filer is the variable that the id of the opened file is assigned to, and what other functions that need to interact with the file are given as input. Not sure of the formal term.

Comment: @OddFunction You claim the opening of the file is successful. How do you know? Reading from an invalid FILE pointer is undefined behaviour. __You absolutely need to check if `fopen` fails. Not doing so is a very commun source of problems__.

Comment: I implemented a check for fopen to test, still hits the same fault.

Comment: Also you claim that `read_file1` works, but you didn't show the code that calls `read_file1`.

Answer (score 1):

At least this is wrong in your code (a very common beginner's error):

```
int  *numTrees, *numLeaves;   // those pointers are not initialized
read_file2(filename, numTrees, numLeaves);
```

instead you want this:

```
int  numTrees, numLeaves;
read_file2(filename, &numTrees, &numLeaves);  // provide the pointers
                                              // to the int variables 
                                              // numTrees and numLeaves
```

Also a check for `fopen` is mandatory:

```
filer = fopen(filename, "r");
if (filer == NULL)
{
  printf("Fatal erorr, file does not exist\n");
  exit(1);
}
```

This will abort program if the files not not exist. In real world programs a more sophisticated error handling should be done, but here at least we eliminate the chance of reading from an invalid FILE pointer.

Comment: Actually, they do point somewhere. Onto a random memory location, where apps and OS may reside.

Comment: @AndreyBelkin "they point nowhere" is a figure of speach. The correct term is "they are not initialized" and dereferencing an uninizialized pointer results in undefined behaviour. And "Onto a random memory location, where apps and OS may reside" is inaccurate: they don't point to a _random_ location but to an _indeterminate_ location.